# How to properly pass an object from XML using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I will try to describe my issue. 
I have the XML document with next structure (don't look at Russian text; it is ok) :

```
    <Books>
    <Book ganre="fantasy">
    <bookId>FD46</bookId>
    <bookName>Меч предназначения</bookName>
    <bookAuthor>Анджей Сапковский</bookAuthor>
    <bookYear>1994</bookYear>
    <bookAvailable>false</bookAvailable>
    </Book>
    <Book ganre="fantasy">
    <bookId>0RD7</bookId>
    <bookName>Башня ласточки</bookName>
    <bookAuthor>Анджей Сапковский</bookAuthor>
    <bookYear>1997</bookYear>
    <bookAvailable>false</bookAvailable>
    </Book>
    <Book ganre="action">
    <bookId>709F</bookId>
    <bookName>Автостопом по галактике</bookName>
    <bookAuthor>Дуглас Адамс</bookAuthor>
    <bookYear>1979</bookYear>
    <bookAvailable>false</bookAvailable>
    </Book>
    </Books>
```

Trying to find element by `bookID` with help of this Xpath

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("Test/Books.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(fileInputStream);

            XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

            Node node = (Node) xPath
                    .evaluate("//Book[bookId/text()='" + bookID + "']", document.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODE);
```

`bookID` - this is user input (for eg like this)

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "cp866");
String bookID;
bookID = sc.nextLine();
```

So idea is to return from xml node from THIS object that we found with current id in a String `<bookName></bookName><bookAuthor></bookAuthor>` so I can put into another xml.

Like

```
String takenBookName = new XMLDocument(xml).xpath("/Books/Book/bookName/text").get(0); //it will doesnt work ;)
```

Comment: please add last element </Books> (so people can copy/paste)

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi resolved

Comment: I've just checked with http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output.
Your request works there. Can you double check XML and your xpath there as well?

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi yes this request will find bookId, but my problem is to get value of bookName from finded object in String for example.

Answer (score 1):

Must work for you.

```
//Book[bookId/text()='709F']/bookName/text()
```